# Webjar scripts not working when using Spring security

Tags: java, thymeleaf

This is how I am calling this three script

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script> 
  <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
  <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js}"></script>
```

Clone this [repo](https://github.com/lieyongchang/RepoWIthIssue.git), the name of this html file is layout.

file path: scr -> main -> resources -> templates -> fragments

or you cam run it in eclipse, open localhost:8080 and inspect web page and go under network tab

**What I have tried:**

- open postman and was able to get a response
- Maven -> update project  and run the application

**Expected result:** it should return a 200 response everytime

**Actual result:** return 302 status everything

Comment: is that not just a redirect that the user agent should follow?

Comment: We can't identify where the redirect is set from your description. Need to debug a little bit yourself.

Comment: I suppose it's spring security redirecting to login page. You should permitAll() under /webjars/**

Comment: @digitalillusion you are right, i have make the changes, see below for my examples

Comment: @Michael Piefel I have change the title of this question, what else can i do so i wont get a down vote for this question?

Answer (score 0):

below are the changes I have make

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()...
    }
```

after that the status became 304 and can work normally